# Python 2.7 Itertools Starmap

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

Have a function, `func` which takes *two* string arguments, The first one works, but according to the itertools documentation, shouldn't the second one work also? The function currently prints a random string, in return, but in the second nothing gets printed

```
func(*("dog", "cat")) //works

itertools.starmap(func, [("dog", "cat")]) //fails without error message, nothing gets printed to screen
```

Perhaps it is too late (or early) at night, am I missing a glaring mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.starmap` returns an iterator; to actually get it to execute you need to iterate through it e.g. using `list`:

```
list(itertools.starmap(func, [("fall", "2007")]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the result of your `starmap()` function call returns an iterator (namely `itertools.starmap` object), but not a list of values themselves.

Your function works fine, though you should take results one-by-one by iterating over:

```
for result in itertools.starmap(func, [("fall", "2007")]):
    # print result here or do some other stuff
```

To get a list of result at start (if you don't need lazy results fetching) - adapt your iterator to list:

```
list(itertools.starmap(func, [("fall", "2007")]))
```

Comment: starmap executes lazily, so it will apply passed values to passed function (make call) when .next() inner method is called (one per .next() method call). list(..) will iterate over those calls and create a list of results for you. for-loop also calls .next() method implicitly on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of results at the start (if you don't need lazy results fetching) - adapt your iterator to `list` (in Python3):

```
>>> list(starmap(lambda x,y:x**y, [(1,2),(3,4)]))
[1, 81]
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I just avoid starmap. Instead I use the following homebrewed function

```
def one_arg(f) :
    return lambda x : f(*x)
```

to and apply it to func.

Comment: You could also just do `func(*x)` without this lambda psuedo-decorator. It's an unnecessary extra function call if you are using apply with it, and if you really wanted to do this you should use it as a real decorator, including using functools.wraps. The original question even gives the simple example `func(*("dog", "cat"))` and is asking about why starmap doesn't return anything.